# How to resolve the Python error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'"?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 108, in get_pyaudio
    import pyaudio
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyaudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speechrecog.py", line 5, in <module>
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 110, in get_pyaudio
    raise AttributeError("Could not find PyAudio; check installation")
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

Comment: Have you tried opening a command line and doing `pip install pyaudio`?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. For everyone else to understand and be able to help you, please consider editing your question. You could start by reading this article: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try reformulating the question. It will help others reproduce the problem and maybe find an answer.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try installing pyaudio (details here https://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/).
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when your program is trying to use a module that you yourself haven't installed. Some modules are built into Python itself like math. The way you need to use pyaudio is to install it into the directory you are already in for this project.

in a terminal window, `cd` to your project directory, run    `python -m pip install pyaudio`

Let me know if that works.